# OSX Routing Between 2 NICs on 2 separate hosts

Tags: networking, routing, mac-osx

A little background: I am building a box that I can ship to a venue that has a Mac Mini and a Sony PTZ camera that connects directly to it via ethernet. I am using a secondary NIC to connect the camera, primary NIC connects to the venues network. From that mac (locally logged in), I can connect, send UDP commands to the camera and everything works.

Now what I want to do, is be able to issue commands from my OTHER mac on the same network and sort of "Proxy" traffic from the primary NIC, to the camera NIC and eventually to the camera. Ultimately these will be connected over a VPN, but for now I am trying to get it working on the same local area network.

Here is a diagram:
[image]

- The camera, is directly connected to mac 1 via ETH2 and the camera has an IP of 192.168.2.50. That NIC has an IP of 192.168.2.15
- Mac 1 also connects to the LAN/Internet with Eth1 and it's IP is 192.168.1.147
- I want to be able to hit 192.168.2.50 from Mac 2. I tried adding static routes on Mac 2 but it wouldn't work.

Comment: Mac 1 needs to be configured to route (not NAT, which is _not_ a substitute for routing) between its two networks. Routers route packets between networks, so you need Mac 1 configured to route packets between the two networks.

Comment: Hey Ron, thanks so much. Any details you can provide on doing that? Can OSX do it natively, or do I need 3rd party software?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know the details of that. If this is a personal network, you could ask on [apple.se] or [su].